# How in Python can I call a function with a variable which is store as a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have problem similar to describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python/), but a bit more complicated. There are BeautifulSoup objects (store in list) and I want to find some other tags. The information which tags I want to find are store in strings. 
I.e.:

```
a= [...] #(list of BeautifulSoup objects)
next="findNext('span')"

b=[ getattr(c,next).string for c in a]
```

doesn't work. What I do wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or incorrect output?  Can you post an example?  "Doesn't work" is not very helpful description of your problem.

Comment: next='findNext("span")'
 compare a1 = [ getattr(c, next) for c in a.atags] to
 a2 = [ c.findNext("span") for c in a.atags]
a1[0] = None when a2[0] = <span class="company_name">Linguamatics</span>
So it works indeed, just not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like what you want is:

```
b = [ eval("c." + next).string for c in a ]
```

This will call `findNext('span')` for each element `c` of the list `a` and form a list of the results of each `findNext` call in the list `b`.

Comment: I made a test and it seems to do what I expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
trees = [...] #(list of BeautifulSoup objects)
strings = [tree.findNext('span').string for tree in trees]
```

or, if you really must,

```
trees = [...] #(list of BeautifulSoup objects)
next = ('findNext', ('span',))
strings = [getattr(tree, next[0])(*(next[1])).string for tree in trees]
```

So I guess the next question is, what's a simple way to turn `"findNext('span')"` into `('findNext', ('span',))` (keeping in mind that there may be multiple arguments)?

Comment: The problems is that "findNext('span')" is a example and it will change from page to page. I plan to read it from a database (or a dictionary). I guess it would address your concern, doesn't it?